# uploading image using HTML canvas

Tags: asp.net, image-processing, image-uploading, todataurl

i am not able to pass parameter "image" as query string in below code.
i am trying to convert convas into image.
 Then toDataURL() passed as a parameter using ajax to save the image. but there is an issue while passing toDataURL() it shows error 500.

```
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        html2canvas(document.querySelector("#jhdj"), { canvas: canvas }).then(function (canvas) {
          //  console.log('Drew on the existing canvas');
        });

            var image = document.getElementById("dvNCVS").toDataURL("image/png");
            image = image.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');

          $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/CodePages/imUpp.aspx/UploadPic',
                data: '{ "imageData" : "' + image.toString() + '" }',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (msg) {
                    alert("Done, Picture Uploaded.");
                }
            });
```